# MySQL: Set "diff" bit when insert different value on duplicate key?

Tags: python, mysql

I have a cronjob (J1) which calculate ~1M customers' product category preference every night. Most customers' preference are stable. But there are exceptions and there are new customers every day. I want to know these changes by setting a "diff" bit to 1. Then another cronjob (J2) can do something (e.g. send notification to them) on such customers and set them back to 0.

The table looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE customers (
  customer_id VARCHAR(255),
  preference VARCHAR(255),
  diff TINYINT(1),
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id),
  KEY (diff)
);
```

AFAIK, `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` doesn't know about whether a non-key value is different. So you can't use something similar to the following, right?

```
INSERT customers AS ("sql for J1") ON DUPLICATE KEY
_AND_PREFERENCE_DIFFERS_ SET diff=1;
```

So what's the best way to do it?

a) Rename table `customers` to `customer_yesterday`. Create a new table `customers` by running J1. LEFT JOIN two tables and set diff bit of `customers`.  (Pros: faster? Cons: need to handle all diffs correctly, e.g. cases when a customer doesn't present in today's output)

b) Loop through output of J1 (using python mysql connector), query `customer` by `customer_id`, and insert only when value is different or it's a new customer. (Pros: easy to understand logic; Cons: slow?)

Any better solutions?

Update:
As @Barmar asked, let's say sql for J1 is a transaction grouping sql, e.g.

```
SELECT 
  customer_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_category SEPARATOR ',')
FROM transaction
WHERE date between _30_days_ago_ and _today_;
```

Comment: What is `sql for J1`? You should be able to make it join with the `customers` table and not return any rows where `preference` is the same as the old value.

Comment: @Barmar Aha, this sounds a good idea. I've updated sql for J1 above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make SQL for J1 a query that uses a `LEFT JOIN` to filter out customers whose preference hasn't changed.

```
INSERT INTO customers (customer_id, preference)
SELECT t1.*
FROM (
    SELECT customer_id, 
           GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product_category ORDER BY product_category SEPARATOR ',') AS preference
    FROM transaction
    WHERE date BETWEEN _30_days_ago_ AND _today_) AS t1
LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON t1.customer_id = c.customer_id AND t1.preference = c.preference
WHERE t1.customer_id IS NULL
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE preference = VALUES(preference), diff = 1
```

I've added an `ORDER BY` option to `GROUP_CONCAT` so that it will always return the categoris in a consistent order. Otherwise, it may result in false positives when the order changes.

I feel obliged to point out that storing comma-separated values in a table column is generally poor database design. You should use a many-to-many relationship table instead.

Comment: Thanks. And a second thank for advice for not using comma-separated values.