# get difference in value in mysql table before updating value

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table (columns: `date` | `rev` | `rev_diff`) where I'm inserting the total rev for month into table, and the total for each month is changing every day.

I'm using `REPLACE INTO` query to update the values. The `rev_diff` column = old rev - new to be inserted rev for that month. Currently I'm getting the values from table and storing in php variable and then find the difference and then insert new values along with the difference.

What i would like to know is if there is way where I can accomplish that with single query if mysql has built in function that can get the difference of rev and put it in `rev_diff` column.

Comment: Please post your code where you having an issue and if you are looking to optimize your code you should use Code Review instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INSERT` with the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` option.

```
INSERT INTO yourTable (date, rev, rev_diff)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rev_diff = rev - VALUES(rev), rev = VALUES(rev);
```

Comment: will that insert the value for the month thats not in the table yet? sorry i forgot to mention that if month doesn't already exist then it has to just insert the rev

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31217176/mysql-set-diff-bit-when-insert-different-value-on-duplicate-key/31217581#31217581 does that help?

Comment: don't quite understand left join and all that yet

Comment: this is my current query to insert $conn->prepare("REPLACE INTO {$strjoin}(date, rev, rev_diff) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"); can i somehow combine your UPDATE part into that ?

Comment: I now realize all that complexity isn't really needed for this, since you don't need to do anything conditional between the old and new values. I'll update the answer with a simpler INSERT statement.

Comment: can date column be key? currently id column is set as primary key (another thing i forgot to mention in original question)

Comment: It has to be a unique key, it doesn't have to be the primary key. I assumed it was, since otherwise your `REPLACE` statement wouldn't update the row.

Comment: yes it is unique key, perfect thank you!!! your solution is actually gonna reduce my code in other part of project as well. Thank you!!!!!